# Unity baked lightmap problem (zigzag shadows)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow, light

There is a reoccurring problem in my unity project. After generating baked lightmaps I get some "zigzag" effect instead of smooth shadows on multiple objects as shown on the attached image. The zigzag runs along the edges of the model.

[image: click for image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons:

- Low lightmap resolution (visible edges)
- Too dim light (low sample count - light fades away quickly)
- Not enough samples on your object
- Low texture resolution (low lightmap details can be applied)

Here are custom settings that we are using in our project, they give pretty good result:
[image: baked light settings]

Comment: Thats a crazy number of samples, it took an eternity to render, but there are still zigzags shown maybe a bit dimmer. I think something else is the root of the problem, however increasing the lightmap size surely is a good idea, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the UV map of the model doesn't have too much stretching because it would also stretch the lightmap and make it look pixelated. This may not be the issue but it's worth checking.